# Castle Windsor resolving and generics

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have the following:

```
public interface ISubject { ... }

public class Subject<T> : ISubject { ... }

public class MyCode<T> {
    ...
    pulic void MyMethod()
    {
        var item = container.Resolve<ISubject>(); //????? how do I pass in T
    }
    ... 
 }
```

In this case how do i do the resolve.

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 14, accepted):

vdhant - That's not how containers are meant to be used.

You want to use `ISubject`, right?. Then if you passed T you're breaking your abstraction, because your caller must know that `ISubject`, is actually a Subject, and more than that, its a `Subject<T>` and that it requires a concrete T.

No container will allow that, but it's a design problem, not tool problem.

One thing to fix your design, would be to make it explicit - change `ISubject` to `ISubject<T>`

Then you could register open generic type `ISubject<>` and bind it to open generic type `Subject<>`.

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ISubject<>))
                            .ImplementedBy(typeof(Subject<>)));
```

Then you'd be able to do

```
var fooSubject = container.Resolve<ISubject<Foo>>();
```

You didn't provide any context so I may be off the track with the answer, but one thing is for sure - you have a design problem.

Comment: Cool so what i means is I need to provide a generic version of the interface and then I can do what I want to do... sounds good to me. 
Cheers

Comment: Happy to help @EhsanSajjad

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic can you help me in understanding, how to integrate wcf all service contracts, or do i need to add all one by one like ``IUserService`` , ``IAuthenticateService`` etc??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad try `WithServiceAllInterfaces` or if you need more control, a custom predicate

Comment: what i need is bind WCF services in web application asp.net mvc, i have researched but not found any proper example, though found some which were incomplete

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Perhaps creating a specific question would help? We're hijacking comments here.

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic ok sure i will post question