# Castle Windsor: Registering Generic Classes with a Non-Generic Interface

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

I have a class that has several dependencies:

```
public class ThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator<TItem, TSearchCriteria, TResult> : IThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator where TItem : class, IThirdPartyItem
    {
        public ThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator(IDataMiner<TSearchCriteria, TResult>[] miners, IThirdPartyItemRepository<TItem> repository, IMappingEngine mapper, IUpdater<TItem, TResult> updater)
        {
            this.miners = miners;
            this.repository = repository;
            this.mapper = mapper;
            this.updater = updater;
        }
}
```

And the relevant Castle registrations look like this:

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel));
container.Register(Component.For<IMappingEngine>().Instance(Mapper.Engine));
container.AddComponent<IThirdPartyItemRepository<ThirdPartyPackage>, ThirdPartyPackageRepository>(typeof(IThirdPartyItemRepository<ThirdPartyPackage>).FullName);
container.Register(AllTypes.Pick()
                    .FromAssemblyNamed(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(TestDataMiner)).GetName().Name)
                    .WithService.FirstInterface());
container.AddComponent<IThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator, ThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator<ThirdPartyPackage,ThirdPartyPackageSearchCriteriaDto,ThirdPartyFlightSearchResultDto>>();
```

However, I'm having real trouble resolving an instance of `IThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator`.

All these are successful:

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IThirdPartyItemRepository<ThirdPartyPackage>>()
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUpdater<ThirdPartyPackage, ThirdPartyPackageSearchResultDto>>()
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMappingEngine>()
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDataMiner<ThirdPartyPackageSearchCriteriaDto, ThirdPartyPackageSearchResultDto>>()
```

However when I try:

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator>()
```

Castle complains:

> Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException:
>   Can't create component
>   'ApplicationServices.ThirdPartyData.ThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator`3'
>   as it has dependencies to be
>   satisfied. 
>   ApplicationServices.ThirdPartyData.ThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator`3
>   is waiting for the following
>   dependencies:
>
> Services: 
>   - IThirdPartyItemRepository`1 which was not registered. 
>   - IUpdater`2 which was not registered.
>
> Keys (components with specific keys)
>   - miners which was not registered.

Am I missing something - or am I expecting too much of Castle to resolve generic dependencies that way?

**Edit**
What I would like to do is explicitly register each concrete `ThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator<TItem, TSearchCriteria, TResult>` that I intend to use against the `IThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator` interface in the application.

I don't want to make the interface generic, as then I wouldn't be able to hold a collection of different `IThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator`.

How can I tell castle to explicitly initialise, for example, a `ThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator<ThirdPartyPackage, ThirdPartyPackageSearchCriteriaDto, ThirdPartyPackageSearchResultDto>`, without having to feed in all the dependencies manually to the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I think you need to register the open generic interfaces first. **Then** you can override a specific implementation.

See [Castle Windsor resolving and generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872413/castle-windsor-resolving-and-generics)

Comment: Hi mausch. I knew you'd be around to answer this one! I don't want to make the interface generic, as then I wouldn't be able to hold a collection of different IThirdPartyDataSearchCoordinator. I've edited the question... any further ideas?

Comment: There are too many classes and interfaces here... Send me a stripped-down solution that reproduces this and I'll check it out.

Comment: Okay, I'm not quite sure how to contact you

Comment: Just put every class and interface in a single file and drop it in http://pastebin.com/ or http://gist.github.com/ and send me the url

Comment: Okay, I think I've narrowed the problem down to something very simple. I want to be able to register generic classes against a non-generic interface, see http://www.codepaste.net/oc1qqu

Comment: At first blush it looks like a bug in Windsor. I'll test it more thoroughly later.

Comment: Registering a generic class with a non-generic interface works fine, all you need to do is container.AddComponent<ICoordinator, SimpleCoordinator<string>>(); I think the testcase wasn't enough to repro your original issue...

Comment: Are you using a different version of Castle? In v1 it doesn't work.

Comment: I've just tried it with v2 and the test still fails. "System.ArgumentException: The type or method has 1 generic parameter(s), but 0 generic argument(s) were provided. A generic argument must be provided for each generic parameter."

Comment: Oh, I see, it doesn't like the Register All Types line. Hmm. I'll work on reproducing the problem with a bigger example then.

Comment: I'm also using v2. Send me a bigger example... RegisterAll was not really necessary in the example you sent me...

Comment: Right, it's taken a while to replicate... I hope you're still following! :-) http://www.codepaste.net/pokd3s

Comment: "We're sorry, but an unhandled error occurred on the server" on codepaste.net :-(

Comment: This setup passes all tests: http://pastebin.com/mcd314b4
It seems that the batch registration (AllTypes) was registering something it shouldn't have registered. When in doubt, use a LINQ expression instead of AllTypes et al, it gives you more control over the registrations (but it will also be more verbose).
Also, use the castle users group (http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users) for future questions, there are more skilled people over there.

Comment: Mausch - many thanks for your time on this! This creates a further problem in that I'm not sure I want to be registering every single class on its own explicit line. The real application is much bigger than the example and that will be a lot of registrations.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I played around for quite a bit and worked a solution. I changed my "AllTypes" registration to only register non-generic types.

```
container.Register(AllTypes.Pick()
.FromAssemblyNamed(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IUpdater<,>)).GetName().Name)
.If(p => !p.ContainsGenericParameters)
.WithService.FirstInterface());
```

Now it all works nicely. I think there's some problem with AllTypes and generic class registrations.

**Update**
Simply placing my generic class registrations before the AllTypes did the trick too.